# there is only one option in a box, how do I get the value of option when I clicked on the option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My option datas come from the database. That's why "select" may have one or more "option".When select has 2 option "change" event is working. it's ok. 
But when there is only one option change (also click and focus) event does not work. How do I get the value of option when I clicked on the option?

```js
$("#box").change(function(){
  var selected=$("#box option:selected").val();
alert(selected);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="box">
  <option value"1">1</option>
  <option value"2">2</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#box").change(function(){
  var selected=$("#box option:selected").val();
alert(selected);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="box">
  <option value"1">1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have one option then you can use **click event** of jquery instead of **change** event

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
if($("#box option").length>1){
  $("#box").change(function(){
    var selected=$("#box option:selected").val();
    alert(selected);

  });
}else{
  $("#box").click(function(){
    var selected=$("#box option:selected").val();
    alert(selected);

  });
   
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="box">
  <option value"1">1</option>
  <option value"2">2</option>
</select>
```